# How can I switch off the yaw damper in an Airbus A350?

Tags: airbus-a350, flight-dynamics, yaw-damper

***How can I switch off the yaw damper in an Airbus A350?*** 
In the A320, this can be done by switching off the FAC, but the A350 doesn't have a FAC switch; it has prim and sec instead of FAC and ELAC.

Comment: I'm curious why you are asking.  Would you mind sharing your interest in the A350, and why you would want to know something so specific?

Comment: I'm an engineer at a flight simulator company and I've just been put on the A350 project but I'm not familiar with the cockpit layout.

Comment: As a simulator engineer, shouldn’t you somehow be able to receive documents from aircraft OEM detailing the systems to be simulated?

Comment: If you want to buy a simulator you pay for the data package but it is the simulator manufacturer who will get it

Comment: @MichaelHall This is a Q&A site that frequently receives specific questions about an aircraft's feature or behavior. You don't need to play security and find out why folks are asking a specific question.

Comment: @zymhan, who says I’m playing security?  I thought it was a very odd question in the specificity it was seeking.  Most questions from the general public are more like how far, how high, how fast, etc.  And if you really needed to know that kind of detail, as Cpt Reynolds points out, you ought to have access to manuals.  The OP satisfied my curiosity, and you don’t need to scold me for asking.

Answer (score 1):

On the simulator normally you can simulate the failure of the yaw damper actuators which has the same effect as switching off the yaw damper.
On the aircraft you can’t do it from the cockpit panels without switching off lot of other functions

Comment: The thing is there are no yaw damper actuators on new A330s, A345 and above. They have all-FBW rudders.

Comment: As far as I remember on Airbus in addition to the ADIRUs you have lateral  specific accelerometers to the FBW; you have to switch off all these by means of push buttons and breakers, but this is not enough because in Airbus you have an emergency autonomous yaw damper unit that uses hydraulic power to generate electrical power to provide yaw damper.

Answer (score 0):

If you prevent the yaw damper function to be calculated it will switch off. As yaw damper is calculated using lateral data from ADIRUs and specific FBW lateral accelerometers you need to switch off all these; the ADIRUs by push buttons and the lateral accelerometers by specific breakers. On some Airbus you still have an emergency AUTONOMOUS yaw damper unit, some models are fully electrical and use up to the battery power, so you pull the relevant breaker, but some models use the hydraulic power to generate their own electricity so you need to switch off the corresponding hydraulics, leaving active the only hydraulic that the autonomous yaw damper does not use.
On the other hand note in **direct** FBW mode the yaw damper is degraded but still functional, so being in direct mode is not sufficient to inhibit the yaw damper. But by putting off the yaw damper most probably you will be in direct law.